# Python selenium find following sibling

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to grab the next sibling

```
<tr id="12345">
   <td>
      <a id="6789">text1</a>
   </td>
   <td>
      text2
   </td>
   <td>
      text3
   </td>
</tr>
```

i was able to extract 'text1' by using this code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@id, '6789')]")
```

i tried extracting 'text2' with this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//a[@id='6789']/following-sibling::td")
```

but i got 'no such element' error

How can i extract 'text2' and 'text3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this xpath instead.

```
//a[@id='6789']/parent::td/following-sibling::td
```

Reason why your xpath did not worked: The td is not a sibling to `a`.

Comment: Works Great! Thank You